# Flutter table structure

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabular, flutter-table

I want to get this structure:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
item 1                                 item 2
item 3                                 item 4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I'd need to have a `Table` with 2 `columns` with 2 `rows` in each `column`, but this is the effect I get:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[

              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                    child: new Text("item 1"),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                    child: new Text("item 3"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                    child: new Text("item 2"),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.teal),
                    child: new Text("item 4"),
                  )
                ],
              )

            ],
          ),
        )
```

I want each `column` to take half of the `width` space available.
On `Android` I'd use the `weight` property and that's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `flex`(by default it's 1) you can separate the two columns and then use the `crossAxisAlignment`to align them items in the beginning :
[image]

```
  new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
    child: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                child: new Text("item 1"),
              ),
              new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                child: new Text("item 3"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                child: new Text("item 2"),
              ),
              new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.teal),
                child: new Text("item 4"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: i am really happy to hear that

Comment: why `flex: 2` on both `Expanded` ? They negate each others

Comment: sorry @RémiRousselet will update my answer  i didn't notice that

Comment: How you can manage text lines it should be equal in the left and right columns.

Answer (score 26):

I would suggest using the Table Widget for consistency and ease as nested rows and columns can get a little messy and far indented.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

```
   ...
Table(children: [
  TableRow(children: [
    Text("item 1"),
    Text("item 2"),
  ]),
  TableRow(children:[
    Text("item 3"),
    Text("item 4"),
  ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a table with Header & scroll.

```
return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            headerRow(), /* Header Row */
            dataRow(), /* Row 1 Data */
            dataRow(), /* Row 2 Data */
            Column(
              children: /* Add row cell data dynamically */,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

headerRow(List<dynamic> titleRowData) {
    return Container(
      height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(100),
      child: Row(
        children: /* Add header cell data dynamically */,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0, 1],
          colors: [skyBlueColor, indigoColor],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```